# Making a connection to APNs with bluehost server

Tags: python, django, apple-push-notifications, bluehost

I wrote some code to connect to APNs and it works great on my local machine. But when I upload and try to run it on my bluehost server it just takes a long time and then times out. After further testing I can't even get connected to the aps at all. I try

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Connection timed out
```

I am thinking it has something to do with my bluehost configuration. I have a dedicated IP address and have bluehost claims that port 2195 is open. Any ideas on why I might not be able to make a connection?

Comment: Most likely you have already checked it, but I would double check that your own firewall allows you to establish this connection.

Comment: Yeah I can make a connection. It's only from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with tech support a second time the problem was that port 2195 wasn't open for outgoing connections. They got it opened and I am now in business.